# Connection Refused problem when testing outside localhost on react and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jsx

i'm currently working on some kind of order system using react for the frontend(port 3000) and express(port 3001) for the backend.

Everything works like a charm as long as i test it on the same macbook that runs the node project. As soon as i test it using a different computer i get the error "Post http://localhost:3001/login net::ERR_Connection_Refused"

The login function looks like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3001/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        em: em,
        pw: pw
      })
.then ...
```

i don't know if it has something to do with cors, which i configured like this in my server.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); // "*"
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});

app.use(cors());
```

in my package.json of the React Server i also got this line "  "proxy": "https://localhost:3001" but i don't really know what it does, as i'm fairly new to react development.

I also tried out setting

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
```

i could get API responses like /orders in json format from a different computer but fetch requests from 3000 to 3001 are still not working.

Maybe you guys got some ideas what the problem could be. Maybe it lies somewhere completely different than the code i shared.

Many thanks in advance!

I experimented around with the proxy line in the package.json as well as with cors but i'm not really sure if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed sounds like a cors problem (which are extremely annoying). You can try adding the proxy like you said in your package.json. Then change the fetch to the following:

```
fetch("/login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    em: em,
    pw: pw
  })
.then ...
```

React should then fetch through the proxy to http://localhost:3001/login

Answer (score 0):

It usually indicates that the server is not accessible from the network you are trying to connect from.

1. Ensure that your **Express** server is **running and accessible**;
2. **Check firewall settings**, make sure that the firewall on the server machine allows incoming connections on the port your Express server is listening on;
3. **Check network configuration**, if you are testing the application on a different machine or network, ensure that the machine running the server has a publicly accessible IP address or is properly configured with port forwarding if behind a router.
4. **Update CORS settings**, the issue might be related to CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) restrictions. To troubleshoot this, you can try temporarily disabling CORS or allowing all origins (*) on the server-side to see if the error disappears. However, keep in mind that this is not a recommended approach for production applications. Instead, configure CORS to allow requests from the specific origin where your React application is hosted.
5. **Check API endpoint**, ensure that the API endpoint URL used in your React application matches the server's actual URL and port.
6. Also, use **Cors** `app.use(cors())` before other calls or enable it for specifics routes as oriented [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#usage);

If you haven't, consider including error handling based on [these](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) guidelines to facilitate the debug process.